# How can I make a TListView header caption centered in a VCL styled application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, vcl-styles

I'm having a list view control (`ListView` here), and I'm filling it by the code like this:

```
var
  Item: TListItem;
  Column: TListColumn;
begin    
  ListView.ViewStyle := vsReport;

  Column := ListView.Columns.Add;
  Column.Width := 200;
  Column.Alignment:= taCenter;
  Column.Caption:= 'Column 1';

  Column:= ListView.Columns.Add;
  Column.Width := 200;
  Column.Alignment := taCenter;
  Column.Caption := 'Column 2';

  Item := ListView.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption := 'Item 1';
  Item.SubItems.Add('Subitem 1');
end;
```

The problem is that when I use a VCL style in my application, the text is not centered in the list view header:

[image]

How can I make the header caption centered in a VCL styled application?

Comment: I tagged this firemonkey, is that right?

Comment: no, its vcl david (fileList is listview). XE6

Comment: I assumed FMX because of your use of fully scope enums. Please can you clarify with an edit and a re-tag

Comment: That does not look like a plain vcl list view. Why are you hiding details from us? If you want help surely it's better to have full disclosure.

Comment: no i am not hiding any details. i shared screenshot of listview on form. i didnt anything without above code. Yes i use theme. Amaktris theme of XE6 themes

Comment: Please add that to the question as I asked, and tag with delphi version. Use of VCL styles are critical. Take a look at your original question and ask yourself if we had any chance of working this out.

Comment: thanks @TLama, i apologize, i am not perfect at delphi, i am starter. idk how to ask truely

Comment: Have you tried doing this without the use of VCL Styles' Do you get same results? If not using VCL styles gives you desired result it means that your VCL Style affects the way how your TListView is rendered which means that you would have to update your VCL style acordingly.

Comment: @Silver, with Windows style it works as expected (at least in Delphi XE3).

Comment: @SilverWarior, also Windows style works for XE6

Comment: Then it's clear it's a styling issue. Does this happen for just the one style or all of them?

Comment: You can modify the style and change this, however it will also change for all column headers. Perhaps there's a VCL style hack to change this on the fly? In the style designer, go to Objects > Header > Section then on the right find TextAlign. That is, if you want this to be system wide. If not, you will need to either do the drawing yourself or find a hack.

Comment: @Jerry thanks, i understood. but this is embarcadero' s mistake :/

Comment: This is just life with vcl styles. I cannot understand the attraction. I can still remember WinAmp.

Comment: @David Tell me about it, we just had a half-year nightmare implementing VCL styles and being able to switch between them on the fly - recreated all icons to show correctly on both light and dark backgrounds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style hook responsible for drawing the column header never checks for the text alignment of the column and always draws text with left alignment, clearly an oversight.

First create a descendant of `Vcl.ComCtrls.TListViewStyleHook` and a class helper for the ancestor so that we can access the private variable we will need.

```
TListViewStyleHookHelper = class helper for TListViewStyleHook
    function getFHeaderHandle: HWnd;
  end;

TListViewStyleHookEx = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TListViewStyleHook)
  strict protected
    procedure DrawHeaderSection(Canvas: TCanvas; R: TRect; Index: Integer;
      const Text: string; IsPressed, IsBackground: Boolean); override;
  end;
```

Fixing the method:

```
uses
  Winapi.Commctrl;


function TListViewStyleHookHelper.getFHeaderHandle: HWnd;
begin
  Result := Self.FHeaderHandle;
end;


procedure TListViewStyleHookEx.DrawHeaderSection(Canvas: TCanvas; R: TRect;
  Index: Integer; const Text: string; IsPressed, IsBackground: Boolean);
var
  Item: THDItem;
  ImageList: HIMAGELIST;
  DrawState: TThemedHeader;
  IconWidth, IconHeight: Integer;
  Details: TThemedElementDetails;
  LListView: TListView;
  DT_Align: Integer;
begin
  FillChar(Item, SizeOf(Item), 0);
  Item.mask := HDI_FORMAT;
  Header_GetItem(getFHeaderHandle, Index, Item);
  if IsBackground then
    DrawState := thHeaderItemNormal
  else if IsPressed then
    DrawState := thHeaderItemPressed
  else
    DrawState := thHeaderItemNormal;

  Details := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(DrawState);
  StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, Details, R);

  ImageList := SendMessage(getFHeaderHandle, HDM_GETIMAGELIST, 0, 0);
  Item.mask := HDI_FORMAT or HDI_IMAGE;
  InflateRect(R, -2, -2);
  IconWidth := 0;
  if (ImageList <> 0) and Header_GetItem(getFHeaderHandle, Index, Item) then
  begin
    if Item.fmt and HDF_IMAGE = HDF_IMAGE then
    begin
      ImageList_Draw(ImageList, Item.iImage, Canvas.Handle, R.Left, R.Top,
        ILD_TRANSPARENT);
      ImageList_GetIconSize(ImageList, IconWidth, IconHeight);
      Inc(R.Left, IconWidth + 5);
    end;
  end;
  if IconWidth = 0 then
    Inc(R.Left, 2);

  DT_Align := 0;

  if Control is TListView then
  begin
    LListView := TListView(Control);
      if (Index > -1) and (Index < LListView.Columns.Count) then
        case LListView.Columns[Index].Alignment of
          taLeftJustify:
            DT_Align := 0;
          taRightJustify:
            DT_Align := 2;
          taCenter:
            DT_Align := 1;
        end;
  end;

  DrawControlText(Canvas, Details, Text, R, DT_VCENTER or DT_Align or
    DT_SINGLELINE or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);

end;
```

And finally we have to register our extended style hook for the TListView control:

```
Initialization
 TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TListView, TListViewStyleHookEx);

Finalization
 TCustomStyleEngine.UnRegisterStyleHook(TListView, TListViewStyleHookEx);
```

[image: example image]

Comment: Actually as stated in my comment in the question, the VCL Styles actually has its own property for this. I haven't tested it though so it might not work (as a lot of other things in VCL styles).

Comment: @JerryDodge, yes, but as I said, the original code never uses that property. The props you see in the Style designer is just a set of inherited properties, it doesn't mean they are used in any way. This is actually more common then it seems when it comes to VCL styles.

Comment: I understood you ask not taking the `TListView` column alignment into account, but I'm talking about that in the VCL Styles - two different properties.  Apparently neither of them are acknowledged. I would except that the setting in the VCL Styles should at least take priority over the actual control.